# When running bot sample code, I get this error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My code is exactly

[This](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/new_member.py)
(With my token of course)

When I run it,  my bot starts up as normal, but when a new person is added to the server, i get this.

```
------
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USRNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 9, in on_member_join
    await client.send_message(server, fmt.format(member, server))
  File "C:\Users\USRNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1152, in send_message
    data = yield from self.http.send_message(channel_id, content, guild_id=guild_id, tts=tts, embed=embed)
  File "C:\Users\USRNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 198, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: NOT FOUND (status code: 404): Unknown Channel
```

(Sorry about it not being in a code block, I'm new to stack exchange)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work anymore because discord removed default channels so sending it to `server` will not work. You should replace `server` with `discord.Object('insert channel id')` if you are using async or `discord.Object(insert channel id)` if you are using the rewrite branch. Note the string vs int difference. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting closer. However, when i run this and a user joins, the bot crashes with the error 

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable


I replaced everywhere the variable Server was called with discord.Object('Mychannelid')

Comment: You only want to change this server, `await client.send_message(server)` ... replace that server with discord.Object('id').

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to discord.py, and I really appreciate your help. Bot is up and running, or at least this part of it. Thanks again!