# Python Discord.py | invite link on_ready issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

With my code i try to send a invite link to the console of each server that it's in, in discord.py's API it says you can write server or channel, but server doesn't seem to work for me.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():

    print(client.servers)
    for value in client.servers:
        invitelinknew = await client.create_invite(destination=value)
        print(invitelinknew)
```

i receive these errors:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Rasmus/Python/discordbot/botnoggi2.py", line 126, in on_ready
    invitelinknew = await client.create_invite(destination=value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2628, in create_invite
    data = yield from self.http.create_invite(destination.id, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 198, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: NOT FOUND (status code: 404): Unknown Channel
```

My problem uses the on_ready command and for loop to check each server, which is not the same as [When running bot sample code, I get this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521971/when-running-bot-sample-code-i-get-this-error)

EDIT:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for server in client.servers:
        channel = next(iter(server.channels))
        invitelinknew = await client.create_invite(destination=channel)
        print(invitelinknew)
```

this code returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Rasmus/Python/discordbot/botnoggi2.py", line 126, in on_ready
    invitelinknew = await client.create_invite(destination=channel)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2628, in create_invite
    data = yield from self.http.create_invite(destination.id, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 198, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: NOT FOUND (status code: 404): Unknown Channel
```

Comment: See https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/969

Comment: And duplicate of [When running bot sample code, I get this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521971/when-running-bot-sample-code-i-get-this-error)

Comment: Not duplicates since i am using on_ready and not on_member_join or on_server_join

Comment: Same problem, same solution. So it’s a duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521971/when-running-bot-sample-code-i-get-this-error has changing the send_message line as the solution, here i am trying to print it into console

Comment: Questions doesn’t have to be exactly the same to warrant a dupe. Both yours and the linked question involved issue of assigning the target destination to a `Server`. Yours was for creating invite, and the linked’s was for `send_message`, the common problem is present throughout discord.py (due to a change in discord API), which was the removal of default channels.

Comment: With your logic, every method involving a target destination in discord.py are allowed to have their “dupe-protected” question although the backend problem is identical (can’t set destination to a `Server`).

Comment: Try printing the channel name or id before creating an invite, and verify that your bot has access to that channel.

Comment: the print command is printing out a category in discord not a text or voice channel

Comment: Hmm. In that case you could try `discord.utils.get(server.channels, type=discord.ChannelType.text)`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is a little out of date on this point.  You can only create invites for channels.

It used to be that servers had a default channel, so a server invite was actually an invite to that default channel.

Older servers had their default channels grandfathered in, but new servers will not have default channels.

Comment: You'll need to choose a channel from `server.channels` and send an invite for that channel instead.  You could choose the first channel in the iterable, or maybe search by name (most servers have a "general" channel).  It depends what you want.

Comment: Just learning python, so i'm not sure how to extract the first item in a iterable.

Comment: `channel = next(server.channels)`

Comment: turns out: TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not an iterator

Comment: `channel = next(iter(server.channels))`, to get an iterator from the iterable first

Comment: i edited my question, since i'm still receiving an error

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an invite to the first available channel, which a lot of the time is done anyway in the application itself, so just do this:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.servers)
    for server in client.servers:
        for channel in server.channels:
            if channel.type == 'Text':
                invitelinknew = await client.create_invite(destination=channel])
                print(invitelinknew)
                break
```

Comment: server.channels does not support indexing.                                                            TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing

Comment: are you using rewrite or async branch?

Comment: In fact, scrap that, try my rewrite of it (edited answer)